# Who was the first non-Lantern superhero to wield a Green Lantern ring?

Tags: dc, comics, green-lantern

What is the first instance in the DC Comics when a superhero that was not a designated member of the Lantern Corps wielded a Green Lantern ring?

To clarify, by "wielded", I mean someone who used it for a while, and properly, rather than someone who just wore it.

Comment: You're going to have to clarify what exactly counts as "wielding" the ring here. Even in the 90s, some non-Corps folks could already throw a light beam or make a basic construct, but that was very limited in time; while others could wield it for longer but did so later. Basically, a third of the characters from [this CBR article "Green Lantern: 15 Other Heroes Who Have Worn The Ring"](https://www.cbr.com/other-heroes-used-green-lantern-ring/) could be the "first", depending on said definition.

Comment: It depends on what would be considered a green lantern ring. The golden age Green lantern Alan Scott wore a ring made from a green meteor that was later retconned to have been an ancient heavily modified Green lantern ring. And this was before tbhe Green lantern corps was even invented in the comic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The earliest example I know of was [the Flash (Barry Allen)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Barry_Allen_(New_Earth)) wielding Hal Jordan's ring in *[Green Lantern Vol 2 #20](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Vol_2_20)*, published in April 1963.

He didn't make heavy use of it, but he did perform a few ring-based feats, like projecting a hand construct in one of the pages below, and shrinking himself in a later one.

[image]

[image]